# AngularJS - how to pass object (created on the fly) with a interpolated data to a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I would like to create a custom directive to which I can pass an object (created on the fly) with interpolated values.

Example:

Newly created array as a parameter:

```
{userName: vm.data.name}
```

vm.data.name should be replaced with controller data.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom directive</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('testDirectiveApp', [])
  .controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var data = {
      name: 'ABC'
    }

    var vm = this;
    vm.data = data;
  }])
  .directive('customDirective', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
    return {      
      scope: {
        customParam: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes){
        scope.$watch('customParam', function() {
          console.log(attributes.customParam, $interpolate(attributes.customParam)(scope), scope.$eval(attributes.customParam));
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testDirectiveApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController as vm">
    Name: <input ng-model="vm.data.name"> <hr/>
    <div custom-directive custom-param="{userName: vm.data.name}"></div>
    <p>{{vm.data.name}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this doable? What I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Comment: Could you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vlKNWpZ9vwc13BtprA9O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a scope variable with the `attributes` object, and not the `scope` object.

In your directive, change `attributes.customParam` to `scope.customParam`

http://plnkr.co/edit/1o4746GamtIcwHekoKyl?p=info